# Prove directly, by contradiction, or contraposition? If the product of two integers is even, at least one of them must be even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Hello I am having some trouble trying to know which way I should go as for this proof: ( we are suppose to use either direct, contradiction or contraposition)

Prove or disprove: If the product of two integers is even, at least one of them must be even.
Im thinking the direct method of proof would work so heres my start:
let a, b be PBAC even integers 
let a = 2m
let b = 2n
the product of 2m and 2n is 4mn
4mn= 2(2mn)
because their both integers, their product must be an integer. Sense we multipling 2mn by 2 it is also even.

now lets have one of them be odd:
let a be PBAC even integer
let b be PBAC odd integer
let a = 2m
let b = 2n + 1
the product: 2m(2n +1) = 4mn + 2n = 2(2mn +1)
m and n are integers so the product is an integer. 
adding 1 is also an integer but it is in the form of a multiple of 2, so it is even.
so for a product to be even, and integer must be even
QED?
Is my proof correct? and how would i do this by contradiction/contraposition

My attempt at contradiction:

Assume the product of two integers a and b are both even. Suppose not that integers a and b are odd
a = (2m + 1)
b = (2n + 1)
let m and n be PBAC integers
ab = (2m + 1)(2n + 1)
ab = 4mn + 2m + 2n +1
ab = 2(2mn + m + n) + 1

Since (2mn + m + n) will be an integer by closure we can conclude that the product ab is an odd integer, which contradicts the assumption.
This means at least one of the integers a or b must be even.
QED?

Answer (score 4):

Your proof isn't quite correct; you've concluded that if one of the integers is even, so is their product. You want to prove that it the *product* is even, then one of the integers was even.

---

The proof by contrapositive is the simplest, I think. The contrapositive simply says that

> If neither integer is even, then the product is not even.

That is, the product of two odd integers is odd. This is easily verified from considering the equality

$$(2k + 1)(2m + 1) = 4km + 2k + 2m + 1 = 2(2km + k + m) + 1$$

Comment: Even the direct proof isn't that bad. Start by  taking a product of two integers $a,b$ that is even. I.e. $a \cdot b=2n$. Now think about factoring $2n$. You want to show that the 2 either goes into the $a$ factor or the $b$ factor.

Comment: Actually, the direct proof requires a fact about prime numbers that the contrapositive proof does not.  Of course, the fact is *true*, but it makes the proof significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction: Assume the product of two integers $m$ and $n$ is even. Suppose not that both the integers are odd. That is $m=2r+1$ and $n=2s+1$ for some $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$. But $mn=(2r+1)(2s+1)= 4rs+2r+2s+1=2(2rs+r+s)+1$ But since $2rs+r+s\in\mathbb{Z}$ we conclude that the product $mn$ is another odd integer which contradicts the assumption. Hence atleast one of the integers $m$ or $n$ must be even.

Answer (score 0):

Let the even integer $x$ be the product of the two integers $m$ and $n$.

$x=mn=2k$ $\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Since $2|mn$ and $2$ is prime, either $2|m$ or $2|n$.

Here is the proof:

> Suppose $p$ is a prime number and $p|ab$. Then either $p|a$ or $p|b$.

To prove this we will show that if $p$ does not divide $a$, then $p|b$. Suppose then that $p$ does not divide $a$. As the only positive integers dividing $p$ are $1$ and $p$, $\gcd(a,p)$ must be $1$ or $p$. It is not $p$ as $p$ does not divide $a$; hence $\gcd(a,p)=1$. Thus $a,p$ are coprime to each other and $p|ab$. It follows that $p|b$, as required.